# Windows Forms C# project witch changing language. System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException

Tags: c#, winforms, exception

When i click button for change language I recieve that exception:

```
System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException
  HResult=0x80131532
  Message=Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "numericalMethods.Resource.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "metodyNumeryczne" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
   at System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.HandleResourceStreamMissing(String fileName)
   at System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.GrovelForResourceSet(CultureInfo culture, Dictionary`2 localResourceSets, Boolean tryParents, Boolean createIfNotExists, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo requestedCulture, Boolean createIfNotExists, Boolean tryParents, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo culture, Boolean createIfNotExists, Boolean tryParents)
   at System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(String name, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(String name)
   at numericalMethods.Localization.LanguageManager.GetLocalizedString(String key) in C:\Users\bekie\Source\Repos\Numerical-Methods\Localization\LocalizationManager.cs:line 28
   at metodyNumeryczne.Form1.UpdateLocalizedStrings() in C:\Users\bekie\Source\Repos\Numerical-Methods\Form1.cs:line 35
   at metodyNumeryczne.Form1.languageBtn_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\bekie\Source\Repos\Numerical-Methods\Form1.cs:line 29
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
   at metodyNumeryczne.Program.Main() in C:\Users\bekie\Source\Repos\Numerical-Methods\Program.cs:line 19
```

There is a link to GitHub with all project tree and code:
https://github.com/N0va1992/Numerical-Methods

I want to change language properly in my app. I tried to use ChatGPT for debug but het shows me the same options all the time, and any of them doesn't work. Feel free to clone repository and look on your VS watch really happend in that code. I'm very begginer with C# and that type of solutions.

Comment: The code switches to en-US but the project appears to only have en-EN defined.

Comment: I tried so hard and got so far but in the end I'm such an idiot... i changed resource name for en-US and everything works... Thanks so much